# I am using PHP FPDF to convert HTML to PDF. Can I use fpdf output() parameters 'I' and 'D' simultaneously?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am collecting form data and generating output to PDF file using PHP and fpdf. I want to directly open generated PDF file in browser and also save pdf file automatically to client side. First I can achieve by using "I" parameter in output() command and later by using "D" parameter. Can I use both commands at the same time so that pdf file will be saved automatically and also user will instantly see PDF file in browser?

Note: I don't want to force additional steps to user such as saving PDF or opening downloaded PDF. Both should be done automatically.

I am able to use Output() "F" and "I" parameters at the same time, but "F" saves file to server side.

I tried following:

```
file = $customer.'.pdf';
$pdf-> output($file,'D');
$pdf-> output($file,'I');
```

And also:

```
file = $customer.'.pdf';
$pdf-> output($file,'I');
$pdf-> output($file,'D');
```

In both cases first line is executed and not later.

Comment: Why overcomplicate? The inline viewer should have the option to download the document, you can't execute both lines since after the first line of execution the script process is terminated, so everything below that line will "die", I mean, there's ways to do it, but do you really need them?

Comment: Can manage but if it is possible then one less thing to worry. Also if I use "F" and "I" parameters one after other then both lines are executed. So why not "D" and "I" that was my contention.

Comment: Both `I` and `D` send headers to the browser, and those headers will conflict. `F` stores the file on the server and doesn't send anything to the user.

Comment: `and also save pdf file automatically`...you can't force this, in _any_ circumstances. Yes, setting the D option will suggest to the browser that the file should be downloaded rather than displayed, but whether that actually happens is entirely down to the settings on the browser which receives it. Users can easily turn that off. It's not in your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why this doesn't make sense, you have to understand a bit about how the web works:

- A "user agent" (normally, a web browser) sends a *request* with a URL and some other data (a method, headers, in some cases body data such as a submitted form)
- A server does whatever it likes with that request, and sends a *response* consisting of a *status*, some *headers*, and some *content*
- The user agent (browser) then decides what to do based on that response

Note that it is *not* possible for the server to send two responses for one request, or to explicitly *command* actions on the browser, only send *suggestions* for what to do with the response.

In the case of FPDF, both the 'D' and 'I' options are sending the *content* of the PDF as the body of the response. The only difference between them is that they send different *headers* - specifically, a `Content-Disposition` header of either "inline" (suggesting that the browser display the content direcly) or "attachment" (suggesting that the browser save the file to a local directory, or show a "Save As..." dialog, as well as a suggested file name).

While there might be some complex trickery you could do with client-side JavaScript, you are best off choosing one or the other:

- Use 'D' and the user can immediately open the file once they've saved it
- Use 'I' and suggest the user presses Ctrl-S or Cmd-S to save it themselves